# background repeat tiled bgImage inside an sprite image?

Tags: css, sprite, background-repeat

Lets say this is our sprite

[image]

(please ignore the black forms) Is there a way to repeat the gray -on the left- tiled image so it looks like a repeated background?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, as far as I know, this is not possible, not even in CSS3.

You will need to separate the images.

There is the `background-clip` property but that controls the clipping of the background image in relation to its *container*, which is something else.